# Matching words with more than two number of words in different data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, textmatching

I have two data frames DF1 and DF2 like this.

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
Issues = c('Issue1, Issue4', 'Issue2, Issue5, Issue6', 'Issue3, Issue4', 'Issue1, Issue5')
Location = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w')
Customer = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
DF1 = data.frame(ID, Issues, Location, Customer)

Root_Cause = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4')
List_of_Issues = c('Issue1, Issue3, Issue5', 'Issue2, Issue1, Issue4', 'Issue6, Issue7', 'Issue5, Issue6')  
DF2 = data.frame(Root_Cause, List_of_Issues)
```

I want to compare both the data frames with "Issues" of DF1 and "List_of_Issues" of DF2 and if more than two words in "Issues" column is there in "List_of_Issues" column in DF2, then I want to populate subsequent "Root_Cause" from DF2.
My resulting data frame should look like DF3.

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Issues = c('Issue1, Issue4', 'Issue2, Issue5, Issue6', 'Issue3, Issue4', 'Issue1, Issue5')
Location = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w')
Customer = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
Root_Cause = c('R2', 'R4', NA, 'R1')
DF3 = data.frame(ID, Issues, Location, Customer, Root_Cause)
```

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.

Comment: Yes i have done it. Sorry for that. I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: @Shiriam Well done. I tried to improve the formatting a bit. Now let's see if someone can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data.table:

**EDIT:** I have edited your sample data to account for multi-root cause eventualities. In this data, `ID==1` corresponds to both R2 and R3.

**Data**

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
Issues = c('Issue1, Issue4, Issue6, Issue7', 'Issue2, Issue5, Issue6', 'Issue3, Issue4', 'Issue1, Issue5')
Location = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w')
Customer = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
DF1 = data.table(ID, Issues, Location, Customer)

Root_Cause = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4')
List_of_Issues = c('Issue1, Issue3, Issue5', 'Issue2, Issue1, Issue4', 'Issue6, Issue7', 'Issue5, Issue6')  
DF2 = data.table(Root_Cause, List_of_Issues)
```

**Code**

```
DF1[, Issues := strsplit(Issues, split = ', ')]
DF2[, List_of_Issues := strsplit(List_of_Issues, split = ', ')]

DF1[, RootCause := lapply(Issues, function(x){

  matchvec = sapply(DF2[, List_of_Issues], function(y) length(unlist(intersect(y, x))))
  ids = which(matchvec > 1)
  str = DF2[, paste(Root_Cause[ids], collapse = ', ')]

  ifelse(str == '', NA, str)

})]
```

**Result**

```
> DF1
   ID                      Issues Location Customer RootCause
1:  1 Issue1,Issue4,Issue6,Issue7        x        a    R2, R3
2:  2        Issue2,Issue5,Issue6        y        b        R4
3:  3               Issue3,Issue4        z        c        NA
4:  4               Issue1,Issue5        w        d        R1
```

Comment: `DF2 = DF2[, List_of_Issues := strsplit(List_of_Issues, split = ', ')]`  Hope we are converting List_of_Issues column to vector here.

Comment: We're splitting each combined string of issues into separate strings.

Comment: Thank you so much. Solution is working fine and it was very helpful

Comment: `DF1 = data.table(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  Issues = c('Issue1, Issue4', 'Issue2, Issue5, Issue6, Issue7', 'Issue3, Issue4', 'Issue1, Issue5'),
  Location = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w'),
  Customer = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
)

DF2 = data.table(
  Root_Cause = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4'),
  List_of_Issues = c('Issue1, Issue3, Issue5', 'Issue2, Issue1, Issue4', 'Issue6, Issue7', 'Issue5, Issue6')
)`  Suppose i have more than one root cause for a single row of Issues as mentioned above. Is it possible to list the root cause by comma separated string of Root_cause

Comment: I have now edited the answer to account for multiple root causes.